# Can ' ' and " " be use interchangeably in SQL?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT
*
FROM 
project_id
WHERE
Genre = 'Comedy'


SELECT
*
FROM
project_id
WHERE
Genre "Comedy"
```

Comment: have you tried these queries ?

Comment: The answer is: No!

Comment: that depends on the databse, as far as i know only mysql supports both as strings

Comment: When should ' ' be used and when should " " be used?

Comment: @nbk, the only tag is <sql>, "_Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL_".

Comment: @jarlh no i think we should include all databases on the market

Comment: Single quotes are for literals. Double quotes are for identifiers, e.g. column and table names.

Comment: @jarlh not in mysql.

Comment: MySQL really is an exception here allowing both depending on certain settings, if I am not mistaken. Confusing the two can lead to unexpected results, so better be strict about them. It is recommended to use names in the database that don't need quotes, e.g. long_table_name.long_column_name. Then you only need quotes for string literals where you always use single quotes. Double quotes won't be necessary then :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, and date, time, timestamp, interval and binary literals.

Comment: @nbk, I say the opposite, keep product specific answers to questions having that dbms tag. (And to avoid confusion, users should add a dbms tag to their questions, especially if using a dbms doing things in its own way.)

Comment: Here is an example where confusing the quotes is leading to a wrong result: https://dbfiddle.uk/ue8nOqb5

Answer (score 0):

No. Single quotes are for string literals. Double are for column names and any other identifiers.

```
SELECT
    "user name" AS username, -- double quotes because the column name has a space
FROM table
WHERE status = 'active'
```

Comment: Not only column names, all identifiers.

Comment: no see my comment

Comment: @nbk Please check the description of the [tag:sql] tag, it says: "If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead. **Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL.**" MySQL is not standard SQL. This question is tagged only with [tag:sql] and not [tag:mysql], so an answer explaining the behavior in standard SQL is correct. Mentioning that this is not true in some nonstandard variants such as MySQL would be a nice-to-have but is not necessary for a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

'' = for string values
"" = identifiers
'' works at any database and some programs will concatenate with "" which can be a trouble at some point.

Comment: It is correct that these are standard SQL, but unfortunately the part about working in "any database" (assuming from context that you mean any major DBMS) is not true, because MySQL for example will not accept doublequotes around identifiers, and instead it will treat them as string values in most cases.

Comment: MySQL did correct their invalid GROUP BY behavior, I hope they can fix this too some day.